# Embedding wxWidget controls ontop of each other

Tags: wxwidgets

I have defined a wxPanel that contains a wxFlexGridSizer which contains 4 rows and 2 columns of controls (wxStaticText and wxTextCtrl).

For atheistic purposes, I want to over lay the content of this sizer with a wxRadioBox (with no radio buttons) as it shows a nice outline around the data I want the user to enter with a little description.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thank you!

Edit:

```
void MyFrame::Initialize_Project_Info() {

//wxStaticText* s = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, _T("")); //Random control assigned to the parent to overide wxEVT_SIZE (check wxFrame documentation)

//To try and implement Project Panel
int xx = 5, yy = 10;
int delta_x = 10, delta_y = 10;


wxBoxSizer* hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
wxFlexGridSizer* fgs = new wxFlexGridSizer(4, 2, 10, 15);
wxPanel* Project_Panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 200), wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T(""));

wxStaticBoxSizer* sbox = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL, Project_Panel, _T("Project Information"));


//Project_Info_OverLay = new wxRadioBox(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, _T("Project Information"), wxPoint(5, 0), wxSize(400, 250), 0, NULL, 1, wxRA_SPECIFY_COLS, wxDefaultValidator, _T(""));


//Note wsSize(width,height).
Project_Name = new wxStaticText(Project_Panel,wxID_ANY,_T("Project:"));
Engineer_Name = new wxStaticText(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, _T("Engineer:"));
CrossSection_Name = new wxStaticText(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, _T("Cross Section ID:"));
Additional_Notes = new wxStaticText(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, _T("Additional Notes:"));


Enter_PN = new wxTextCtrl(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_PROCESS_TAB, wxDefaultValidator, _T(""));
Enter_EN = new wxTextCtrl(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_PROCESS_TAB, wxDefaultValidator, _T(""));
Enter_CSN = new wxTextCtrl(Project_Panel,wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_PROCESS_TAB, wxDefaultValidator, _T(""));
Enter_AN = new wxTextCtrl(Project_Panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250,100), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_PROCESS_TAB | wxTE_MULTILINE, wxDefaultValidator, _T(""));

fgs->Add(Project_Name);
fgs->Add(Enter_PN, 1, wxEXPAND);
fgs->Add(Engineer_Name);
fgs->Add(Enter_EN, 1, wxEXPAND);
fgs->Add(CrossSection_Name);
fgs->Add(Enter_CSN, 1, wxEXPAND);
fgs->Add(Additional_Notes);
fgs->Add(Enter_AN, 1, wxEXPAND);

sbox->Add(fgs);

Project_Panel->SetSizer(sbox);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of such layout? Can you do a sketch and put it here? Maybe you are looking for the wxBoxSizer with the square (wxStaticBoxSizer)?

Comment: @Igor I had something like this in mind: https://imgur.com/a/YXETUV1  The data entry field has been already defined, and I just want to put around it a radio box

Comment: @Igor Yes wxStaticBoxSizer was the solution ! However, the outline is being added to the entire panel, and not just around the wxFlexGrid. I have included the code in my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Just change

```
 Project_Panel->SetSizer(sbox);
```

to

```
hbox->Add(sbox, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL));
Project_Panel->SetSizer(hbox);
```

---

Although not part of you're question, I think a better option instead of specifying the horizontal and vertical gaps for the flex grid sizer would be to use sizer flags to define the gaps.  This will help your forms be more flexible when dealing with high dpi screens.

To do this, define the sizer like this:

```
wxFlexGridSizer* fgs = new wxFlexGridSizer(4, 2, 0, 0);
```

And then add elements to it like this:

```
fgs->Add(Project_Name,
         wxSizerFlags().Align(wxALIGN_RIGHT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
                       .Border(wxTOP|wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT));
fgs->Add(Enter_PN,wxSizerFlags().Expand().Border(wxALL));
fgs->Add(Engineer_Name,
         wxSizerFlags().Align(wxALIGN_RIGHT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
                       .Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT));
fgs->Add(Enter_EN, wxSizerFlags().Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT));
fgs->Add(CrossSection_Name,
         wxSizerFlags().Align(wxALIGN_RIGHT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
                       .Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT));
fgs->Add(Enter_CSN,
         wxSizerFlags().Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT));
fgs->Add(Additional_Notes,
         wxSizerFlags().Align(wxALIGN_RIGHT).Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT));
fgs->Add(Enter_AN, wxSizerFlags().Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT));
```

This produces this layout:

[image]

(I've also aligned the static texts next to their text boxes.  You can remove the `Align(wxALIGN_RIGHT)` parts if you don't like this.)

---

I realize, dealing with sizers can be tricky for newcomers to wxWidgets.  There are some graphical gui builders such as [wxFormbuilder](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder) or [wxCrafter](https://wxcrafter.codelite.org/) that you might find helpful.

Comment: thank you for covering. ;-) I'd also add wxGldade to the list.

Comment: Also for my understanding - how is the gaps defined for flex grid sizer when they are set to 0 in constructor?

Comment: The idea is to use the `Border` part of the sizer flags to keep a distance of 1 border of space between each item in the grid.  (Currently that's 5 pixels. Some commits were recently added so that the space will adjust appropriately on high dpi displays.) Basically 1) no items in the left column are given a right border, and 2) only the first row gets a top border and bottom border (all other rows only get the bottom border). I admit it is a little tricky, but if you think about it, putting those 2 things together give a single border all the way around and between each item in the grid.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Are the GUI builders you mentioned software that allows me to develop the GUI without coding ? How would something like wxCrafter interface with other C++ code (for example functions to add numbers)?

Comment: With wxFormBuilder, you can simply cut and paste the code it generates into your project.  That's not the best way to use it, but if you're just starting out it will do.  The correct way to use them is to integrate them with your IDE.  wxFormBuilder integrates well with codeblocks but getting the full setup can be a little tricky. Here is a [guide](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=46125).  I'm not really familiar with wxCrafter, but it is made by the developer of the CodeLite IDE and should integrate well with it. It should work with other IDEs but I have no experience there.